# How to generate an idea project which has "JavaFX" artifact with SBT?

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, javafx, sbt, code-generation

With the [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) plugin, I can generate idea project for a sbt project.

But what if I want it to be a javafx project? Which should have the "JavaFx" artifact. I can add it manually in idea once, but I don't want to do it every time.

If I add the "JavaFx" artifact, there will be one new file created in the `.idea` directory:

```
.idea
    artifacts
        mypro.xml
```

with the content:

```
<component name="ArtifactManager">
  <artifact type="javafx" name="mypro">
    <output-path>$PROJECT_DIR$/target/idea_output/artifacts/mypro</output-path>
    <root id="root">
      <element id="archive" name="mypro.jar">
        <element id="module-output" name="mypro" />
      </element>
    </root>
  </artifact>
</component>
```

Is it possible to let sbt generate this file when run `gen-idea`?

Comment: Hi, Just wondering for which use case do you need to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it easily with the [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) plugin. What you could do though is define your own command `gen-idea-fx`, which would run the original `gen-idea` and then generate the file you want.

#### build.sbt

```
val generateIdeaFx: State => State = { state =>
  val newState = Command.process("gen-idea", state)
  val extracted: Extracted = Project.extract(newState)
  import extracted._
  val projectName: String = (name in currentRef get structure.data).get
  val artifactName: String = (artifact in (currentRef, Compile, packageBin) get structure.data).map { a =>
     a.name + a.extension
  }.get
  val artifactXml =
    <component name="ArtifactManager">
      <artifact type="javafx" name={projectName}>
        <output-path>$PROJECT_DIR$/target/idea_output/artifacts/{projectName}</output-path>
        <element id="root">
          <element id="archive" name={artifactName} />
        </element>
      </artifact> 
    </component>
  val outputFile = (baseDirectory in currentRef get structure.data).get / ".idea" / "artifacts" / s"$projectName.xml"
  IO.write(outputFile, artifactXml.mkString)
  newState
}

val genIdeaFx = Command.command("gen-idea-fx")(generateIdeaFx)

commands += genIdeaFx
```

Now you can generate Idea project by calling `gen-idea-fx`.